# Sorting an array by calling swap by value

Tags: c++, sorting

The question : Create one array of 10 integers. Use the initializer to fill your array data with {10,5,8,55,43,87,42,12,25,7}. Write a sort a function sortArray that will call a swap function. The swap function will be called by value. Rewrite another sort function sortArray2 that will call a swapByRef function.

My code :

```
void swap (int x, int y)
{
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

void sortArray (int A[], int n)
{
    int i,j,minIndex,temp;

    for (i=0 ; i<n-1 ; i++)
    {
        minIndex = i;
        for (j=i+1 ; j<n ; j++)
            if (A[j] < A[minIndex])
                minIndex = j;
        swap (A[i],A[minIndex]);
    }
}

void swapByRef (int &x, int &y)
{
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

void sortArray2 (int A[], int n)
{
    int i,j,minIndex;

    for (i=0 ; i<n-1 ; i++)
    {
        minIndex = i;
        for (j=i+1 ; j<n ; j++)
            if (A[j] < A[minIndex])
                minIndex = j;
        swapByRef (A[i], A[minIndex]);
    }
}

int main ()
{
        int A[10] = {10,5,8,55,43,87,42,12,25,7};
        sortArray (A,10);
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        cout<<A[i]<<endl;
        int B[10] = {10,5,8,55,43,87,42,12,25,7};
        sortArray2 (B,10);
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        cout<<A[i]<<endl;

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

sortArray doesn't sort the array. How can I write this code?

Comment: That swap only swaps local copies of the values passed to it. Doesn't really help much. Use `std::swap`.

Comment: You should take a look at `std::swap`.

Comment: If this is an assignment and you have to implement a swap by value function, you can only do so by passing pointers (but that's like cheating)

Comment: BTW, you are printing 2 times the same array A.

Comment: Since this seems to be a programming exercise to teach the difference between passing parameters by value as opposed to by reference I think std::swap isn't going to help too much. I think the point of the exercise is that swapping by value will not work (unless you pass the pointers which is technically passing by value :P)

Answer (score 1):

```
Write a sort a function sortArray that will call a swap function. The swap function will be called by value.
```

It is impossible. swap function called by value does nothing. From where the problem is?

Comment: Well, the function does something - it simply doesn't alter any values of interest. It's pure overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your teacher just want you to understand the difference between passing by value and passing by reference, through this type of question. So now you realize that passing by value will not change the calling functions' variable value.